# How can get a video to play using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML with a video element with no controls and a button to play the video.
But when I try to play the video using the button, it doesn't do anything.
I don't get any error in the console, and the video just doesn't play.
I can't figure out what can possibly be wrong.
The video plays perfectly when I add the controls attribute in the video tag, but my aim is to not use browsers controls and to build my own controls.

Here is a sample of my code. I used this random video here just so the source is valid.
I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const playButton = document.querySelector('button');

playButton.addEventListener('click', video.play);
```

```html
<video>
<source src="https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/apis/video-audio/finished/video/sintel-short.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
<button>Play</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code is that when the video.play method is supplied as an event listener function, it loses its context and fails. The problem can be resolved by enclosing the method in an anonymous function. **Please check the playButton.addEventListener(){...} function below:**

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const playButton = document.querySelector('button');
playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 video.play();
});
```

```html
 <video width="320" height="180">
    <source src="https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/apis/video-audio/finished/video/sintel-short.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <button>Play</button>
```

Comment: Wow. Works seamlessly ! You've just made my day. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: I edited my code with the anonymous function and it's working like a charm, but only in Firefox. It's there a work-around for it to work also in Chrome, Edge... ?

Comment: Please try using **video.play.bind(video)();** inplace of **video.play()** . Btw, in my chrome it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks. When I run the code on vscode through live server, it works only on Firefox. When I don't use live server it works everywhere else. This is so annoying.

Comment: Have you tried, restarting the **LiveServer** .

Comment: Yes I did. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried in my PC by installing LiverServer and its working. Maybe its  an issue with other things. Try:

* Opening Chrome incognito mode
* Restarting your PC
* Using Five Server

Comment: Problem resolved. I reinstalled LiveServer and restarted my PC. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Change your eventListener's `listener` to:

```
playButton.addEventListener("click", () => video.play());
```